# Eclipse: Incompatible JVM

Tags: eclipse, java-8, jvm, java-17

He instalado Eclipse y la primera vez se abrió correctamente pero luego he sido incapaz de acceder a él.
El primer error que me aparecía es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fisgando por Internet, averigüé que modificando el archivo .ini y añadiendo la ruta del javaw.exe del java más actual que tenga (17.0.2) funcionaría.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al realizar el cambio y guardar el archivo, al iniciar Eclipse, me aparece este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Algún consejo para arreglar este problema y que pueda acceder de nuevo a Eclipse?

Comment: Me pasaba eso hace tiempo, pero hoy en día Eclipse me arranca incluso si no tengo Java instalado (ni idea como hacen), por lo que no recuerdo como lo solucionaba. Dices que tienes la versión Java 17, sin embargo Eclipse te dice que tienes la 8 y requiere de la 11+. También cuando cuando cambias la ruta a donde la 17 no encuentra ese javaw.exe. Por decir algo ¿Existe? ¿Que dice el comando `java -version`?

Comment: @JFrame el comando java -version me dice que tengo la versión 17.0.2